# javascript delete matching rows of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array structure like below from whch i need to delete all the entries having value vik

```
[{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
]
```

iterating using for loop with splicing matching values vik screws up. what is the best way to do this.

my code is:

```
for(let obj of filterList){
        var i =0
        for(let lead of this.core.leadLocalList){
          console.log("comapring:" + lead.campaign)
          if(obj.value == lead.campaign){
            console.log("matched")
            this.core.leadLocalList.splice(i,1)
          }else
            i++
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array filter method to get the desired result.
[Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = [{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "jack"},
{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
{"type" :"x", value: "vik"},
];

const result = data.filter(item => item.value != "vik");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lodash`. It's a dash-ing simple application.

With [`_.remove()`](http://lodash.com/docs#remove) like so:

```
_.remove( filterList, {
    value: 'vik'
} );
```

Or, with ES6, you can do the following:

```
const filtered = filterList.filter( row => row.value !== 'vik' );
```

However, if the application grows complex and you want something a little more advanced, you can take advantage of the predicate function and determine the filtering based on that:

```
_.remove( filterList, ( obj ) => {
    return ( obj.propertyOne !== SOME_CONSTANT ) && ( ... )
} );
```